# Replace a word after matched word with incrementing values

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file like this -

```
   !
   interface csa2549abA
   xxxx
   yyyy
   zzzz
   !
   interface aso23apwoeAe
   aaa
   bbb
   ccc
   !
   interface FastEthernet0/1
   ppp
   qqq
   rrr
   !
```

and so on.

What I want is  to rename the `interfaces` that look like hashes to something more coherent but  **not the ones that makes sense**  and make the output like  this.  **The key difference between ones that makes sense and the ones that don't is that the ones that are hashes have numbers in between the name.**  The ones that make sense always end with numbers. The output should look like this -

```
   !
   interface ethernet1
   xxxx
   yyyy
   zzzz
   !
   interface ethernet2
   aaa
   bbb
   ccc
   !
   interface FastEthernet0/1
   ppp
   qqq
   rrr
   !
```

and so on. Each interface is just an increment on the values of the `ethernet` term.
Also assume that there are multiple files each of this type which can be taken as input.

What I have right now is `sed -i 's/^interface .*$/interface Ethernet/' *` but this just replaces the values of every interface value with Ethernet. I was wondering if there was a command to just increment the last part of `Ethernet` to represent something like I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since arithmetic is required, `sed` is *not* the right tool.  The solution below uses `awk`.

### Answer for revised question

You say the unwanted hashes always have names that include a number followed by a  letter.  In that case:

```
$ awk '/^interface .*[[:digit:]][[:alpha:]]/{$0="interface ethernet" ++f} 1' file1
!
interface ethernet1
xxxx
yyyy
zzzz
!
interface ethernet2
aaa
bbb
ccc
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
ppp
qqq
rrr
!
```

How it works:

- `/^interface .*[[:digit:]][[:alpha:]]/`

  This selects only those lines that start with `interface` and which also later include a number followed by a letter.
- `$0="interface ethernet" ++f`

  The lines selected as above are changed to `interface ethernet` and a number and the number is incremented each time.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

To change the file in-place, assuming that you are using a modern GNU awk, use:

```
awk -i inplace '/^interface .*[[:digit:]][[:alpha:]]/{$0="interface ethernet" ++f} 1' file1
```

### Answer for original question

```
$ awk '/^interface /{$0="interface ethernet" ++f} 1' file
!
interface ethernet1
xxxx
yyyy
zzzz
!
interface ethernet2
aaa
bbb
ccc
!
```

To change the file in-place and assuming a modern GNU awk, use:

```
awk -i inplace '/^interface /{$0="interface ethernet" ++f} 1' file
```